# Автодополнение для Си

Tags: c, sublime-text, sublime-text-3

Меня интересует *автодополнение* кода для *Си* в *Sublime Text 3*. Мне нужно, чтобы после подключения заголовка какой-то плагин давал подсказки, подобно intellisense из Visual Studio. Я "нагуглил" какие-то Clang autocomplete и тому подобное, но они нормально не работают.

Все мои плагины:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из автодополнений у меня есть ключевые слова а-ля struct, typedef, типы переменных etc. Но нет автодополнения (или, можно сказать, подсказок) по подключаемым файлам. Например, тот же stdio.h — у меня автоподолнение только *ОДНОЙ* функции printf.

Comment: Вполне возможно что не существует. Да и зачем они вам, если есть функции strcat, stract_s, strstr, strchr, strrchr и еще более чем много функций, начинающихся со "str", которых вы не помните? Плагин не подскажет зачем оно надо.

Comment: Пусть так, но всё же я не отказался бы. Я не попробовал ещё один плагин — C Improved . Но при попытке скачать его через менеджер пакетов — 
`Unable to download C Improved. Please view the console for more details.
ignored packages updated to: ["Vintage"]
reloading Packages/User/Package Control.sublime-settings
reloading Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings`
это в консоли + первая строка также появляется в виде окна с ошибкой. Можно как-то поставить руками? НА GitHub лежат исходники, но как собрать и поставить я не понятия не имею.

Comment: В душе не знаю можно или нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте [вот это](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeClang). Он, технически, должен выбирать все функции, из заголовков, что у вас подключены. Подробнее про установку [на Хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/167353/).

Если у вас линукс, то можно [заставить его работать под ST3](http://blog.aquatoney.net/use-sublimeclang-in-sublimetext-3/), но вроде бы [и под виндой можно](http://www.rightinfonow.com/install-sublimeclang-sublime-3/).

Comment: Спасибо большое. Кое-как я поставил под свой Win7 этот плагин, но работает как в Visual Studio.